# .NET MAUI WebSocket doesn't work on android 5 and 8

Tags: c#, android, websocket, maui, system.net.websockets

On my android 11 device my websocket works fine, but when i try to run it on older phone with android 5 or 8, it doesnt work and it only says `Unable to connect to the remote server`
Is there some way to make it works ?
I am using `System.Net.WebSockets;`

```
async Task StartWebSocketAsync()
{                
    await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://url?token=" + Token), t);      
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await ReadMessage();
        }
    }, t, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    SendMessageAsync(msg);
}
```

```
async Task ReadMessage()
{
    WebSocketReceiveResult result;
    var message = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[4096]);
    do
    {
        result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(message, t);
        if (result.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            break;
        var messageBytes = message.Skip(message.Offset).Take(result.Count).ToArray();
        string receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes);
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(receivedMessage);
        Status = (string)jsonObject["data"]["state"][0][1];
    }
    while (!result.EndOfMessage);        
}
```

```
async void SendMessageAsync(string message)
{
    var byteMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    var segmnet = new ArraySegment<byte>(byteMessage);

    await ws.SendAsync(segmnet, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, t);
}
```

Comment: Try  updating kernel.  See : https://trendoceans.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-to-5-16-release/#:~:text=The%20first%20thing%20to%20do%20before%20upgrading%20the,install%20headers%2C%20modules%2C%20and%20images%20for%20kernel%205.16.

Comment: Thank you for idea, and maybe that could work, but i need some code solution inside Visual Studio

Comment: Older kernels may not support the encryption mode.  Since Net 4.7.2 encryption for TLS is done in the operating system.  The operating system has to support the encryption mode.   To do in Net you would have to disable the Operating System option and use Net for TLS.  Then you would have to get a HTTP library that supported TLS and use OpenSSL (or equivalent).  I would check the csproj (open in notebook) and see if the option for TLS is Net or operating system.

Comment: Yeah, it's in encryption, when i connect to unsecured websocket it works, i tried to find where i can change that setting, but i didnt find it

Comment: You are using HTTP (not HTTPS secure).  The server usually has HTTPS required.  To disable on server probably requires a registry change.

Comment: You need to use the latest Android 5 and Android 8 updates.

Comment: It only dont work on .NET MAUI app.
In Xamarin app it works fine.
I copied this from xamarin project where secure websocket work on android 8.
`
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android'))">
            <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
            <AndroidTlsProvider></AndroidTlsProvider>
      </PropertyGroup>
`
But after i paste it in my .NET MAUI project file, when i run app it crash on startup.

Comment: See following which is from March.  Things may have changed : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/788451/enable-tls-12-on-net-maui-on-android-vs-2022-previ.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: Also : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/8131?force_isolation=true